# Android EditText not focusing

Tags: android, android-layout

Here's my problem, I have a very simple layout displaying 2 EditText's, one for a title and other for a description. Here is the xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:weightSum="1">

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="63dp"
            android:id="@+id/title_field"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:hint="@string/titleFieldHint"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:textSize="8.5pt"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

    <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/description_field"
            android:hint="@string/descriptionHint"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textSize="8.5pt"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I start the activity with this layout keyboard shows focusing title_field, and so I can write and click on the other field (while keyboard is still opened) and write a description. However, if I hide the keyboard it won't show up again (keyboard) unless I click on title_field, so description_field does not respond, besides title_field supports selection out of the box (including contextual action bar) while description_field won't let me even select.

I'm just beginning android development, is there something I am missing?

Comment: Your layout height is 0dp for the description `EditText`. Is that a typo?

Comment: @dcharms no it is not. I actually changed it from match_parent, and the IDE (IntelliJ) said 0dp has better performance.

Comment: @user3956566 Sorry maybe I didn't explain properly. The layout shows just fine, however I cannot select (contextual action bar does not open) text in description_field while I can in title_field, and also when keyboard is hidden I can only make it appear by clicking on title_field because it won´t appear clicking on description_field. (edited just in case)

Comment: @user3956566 Thank you, if you need a code source let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out `android:textIsSelectable="true"`.

OR

Edit:

If you need to be able to keep the text to use as part of the new edit text:

Change android:hint to andoid:text to be able to use the text with the keyboard. However, it is still needing to go back to the first edittext if the keyboard is closed, it will then stay open for the second edtitext.

I would be using height as "wrap_content" for both edittext boxes.

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:text="descriptionHint"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Comment: It solved the focus problem (it was one of the lines that I added when I was losing my head) but still cannot select text on description_field, do you know why is that?

Comment: Yup I mean basically that. I'm asking mostly because it is weird that it works on one EditText (as I pointed out before it actually shows the contextual action bar) but the other does nothing.

Comment: Hey but your previous answer actually solved that problem just as I commented to @Gaurav post

Comment: Current answer is just fine

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have the keyboard when a particular activity starts like search activity, then use this code in your manifest -

Note - It will pop up keyboard as soon as user landed on activity...

```
<application ... >
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" ... >
    ...
</activity>
...
```

Also you can do it your java file too. With Java you can get more control on keyboard appearance.  Here is the code for it -

```
public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
if (view.requestFocus()) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```

Just call method showSoftKeyboard() to pop up the keyboard !!

Hope I help you !! 
Cheers!

[Refrence Android Development Article](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html)

Comment: That problem was solved by removing android:textIsSelectable="true", right now my remaining problem is that I cannot select i.e. copy/move etc. text from description_field. Thanks anyway!

Comment: To go to second text is majorly depend upon user using your app ! You can not get two editText focused at same time, as far I know. Its better to leave it on user to interact to your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/startJourneyLinearLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/startJourneyLinearLayout"
    android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: Please explain what this is and how it solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

Well for focusing a edittext, you can use the code

```
private void requestFocus(View view) {
        if (view.requestFocus()) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }

//Function Call
requestFocus(yourEditetxt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue with EditText, I was check many blog to find out solution for this error, but didn't solution.

Than check theme section where I put full screen line as default theme(AppTheme)

```
style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

and this was creating a problem to load soft Keyboard on screen.
I just try above code and its just open soft Keyboard not working, What I was typing that not display in EditText.

and I just change Theme from default to this one and its working fine.

```
style name="PhoneActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight"
```

Answer (score 0):

add two attribute **focusableInTouchMode** and **focusable** fixed my problem

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true"/>
```